# remove http query parameter from url htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to shorten my URI to just my site address that is

```
http://www.abcdef.org/index.php?pg=23
http://www.abcdef.org/histop.php?pg=1
http://www.abcdef.org/other.php?pg=29
```

to

```
www.abcdef.org
```

How can I rewrite this using my `.htaccess file? I read a lot of articles but could not find any solution.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How will just `www.abcdef.org` tell you want page to be shown?

Comment: I have created a system in PHP which has some logic defined to generate requested page according to URL http query parameter and send it to client. And the client should see only www.abcdef.org instead of sending complete URI

Comment: @Rafael it is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use Redirect directive

```
Redirect /foo.html /bar.html
```

[Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

But understand when the user types in whatever URL it will map to your index file in your case.  But you can't just hide every URL to the domain name...it doesn't work that way.